# Не переключается слайд при клике на thumbs swiper js

Tags: javascript, swiper

При клике на thumbs не переключаются слайды на основном слайдере. Thumbs функционирует как отдельный слайдер.

HTML

```
       <div class="swiper halls-slider-top">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper halls-slider__items">
            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <img
                class="halls-slider__img"
                src="img/halls/1.jpg"
                alt="big img"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <img
                class="halls-slider__img"
                src="img/halls/2.jpg"
                alt="big img"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <img
                class="halls-slider__img"
                src="img/halls/3.jpg"
                alt="big img"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <img
                class="halls-slider__img"
                src="img/halls/4.jpg"
                alt="big img"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <img
                class="halls-slider__img"
                src="img/halls/5.jpg"
                alt="big img"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="swiper halls-slider-thumbs">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper halls-slider__thumbs-items">
            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <img class="halls-slider__img" src="img/halls/2.jpg" alt="thumb img"/>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <img class="halls-slider__img" src="img/halls/3.jpg" alt="thumb img"/>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <img class="halls-slider__img" src="img/halls/4.jpg" alt="thumb img"/>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <img class="halls-slider__img" src="img/halls/5.jpg" alt="thumb img"/>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <img class="halls-slider__img" src="img/halls/6.jpg" alt="thumb img"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

JS

```
var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.halls-slider-thumbs', {
    spaceBetween:10,
    slidesPerView:5,
    freeMode:true,
    loop:true,
    centeredSlides:true,
    slideToClickedSlide:true,
    loopedSlides:5
  });
 
  var galleryTop = new Swiper('.halls-slider-top', {
    effect:'fade',
    slidesPerView: 1,
    loop: true,
    thumbs:{
      swiper: galleryThumbs
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При подключении swiper js через npm необходимо импортировать модули.

```
import  {Swiper,  Autoplay, EffectFade, Navigation, Pagination, Thumbs } from 'swiper';
Swiper.use([ EffectFade, Navigation, Pagination, Thumbs]);
```